# How to get maximum of a column in google sheet that contains string header?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am very new to google-sheets and learning formulas.

I was trying to calculate the maximum value of a column which contains some strings.
How to get the maximum value?

## MWE

```
A    B      C
day price quantity
feb1 10   2
feb2 0.06 6
feb3 NO   8
feb5 10   2
```

## My attempt

```
=MAX(B:B)
```

Obviously this does not work and it requires some array manipulation and regex. I was wondering how to achieve that.

Comment: The formula works giving `10` as the result. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAX` works only with numbers. your B column (or some cell in B column) is most likely formatted as plain text so either change that or use:

```
=INDEX(MAX(IFERROR(B:B*1)))
```